# How to open GUI applications on remote machine logged in via SSH on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, x11

I am logging into a remote Fedora 12 machine via SSH. I have enabled X11 forwarding by passing `-X` parameter to ssh. I also tried trusted forwarding with `-Y`. Both of them fail with `(gedit:3711): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display`, when I try opening a file with gedit on the remote machine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running a local X11 application first. If that doesn't work, reinstall [Xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) and log out and back in again.