# What is the analog to the $DISPLAY variable to trigger launch of the GUI apps via SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh

On Linux you can login via SSH or a tty and trigger a launch of a GUI application in completely different graphical session:

```
DISPLAY=:0 my-application
```

How to do it on Mac?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193483/how-to-open-gui-applications-on-remote-machine-logged-in-via-ssh-on-os-x